# Some symbols are not being rendered properly

Tags: fonts

Here is the my MWE. I am trying to import `(` and `)` delimiter symbols from `stix.sty` into the computer modern and i get some symbols don't render properly.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{xlargesymbols}{LS2}{stixex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen}{operators}{"2E}{xlargesymbols}{"00}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{operators}{"2F}{xlargesymbols}{"01}

\begin{document}
  \textbf{Question.} Let $|B|\equiv i \pmod{3}$
\end{document}
```

and the output i get for this is [image] its clear that the `\pmod` command is not working properly? Why so? What should i do to rectify this?

Comment: You're missing the part of your example where the parenthesis does work.  In fact, you could trim the document part of the example down to `$() \binom{n}{k}$` to show the problem.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the char position wrong. In my font table the codes are `"28` and `"29` for the small symbols. This got confirmed in the documentation for `stix` (`texdoc stix`)

So:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{xlargesymbols}{LS2}{stixex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen}{operators}{"28}{xlargesymbols}{"00}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{operators}{"29}{xlargesymbols}{"01}

\begin{document}
  \textbf{Question.} () Let $|B|\equiv i \pmod{3}$
  \[
  \left(\frac{a^{\frac{1}{2}}}{n}\right)
  \]
\end{document}
```

producing:

[image]

Comment: Which font table are you referring to? I looked up the `stix.sty` and copied the command

Comment: Also please do help with the char codes for the lbrace rbrace commands, again i am facing a similar problem

Comment: @S.C. I'm using the O.S. font table. Also you can do `texdoc stix` and gives you the same codes as mine

Comment: @S.C. `lbrace` should be `"7B` and `rbrace` `7D`

Comment: Yeah i see it. So should the command line be `\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}{\mathopen}{operators}{"7B}{xlargesymbols}{"00}`??

Comment: How do i get to know what numbers i should be using? Like 7B and 7D i see it in the texdoc stix file, but what about that "00 and "01 thing?

Comment: @S.C. I really think you should post another question about it, describing what you want to do exactly and the problems you have. This way this question will be kept "clean" and also your question will gain more visibility for future users